# NullPointerException issue when calling method inside run method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-handler

I keep getting a null pointer exception when calling the below method inside a run method.

```
protected void swTimerDisplay()
{
 String display;
 long now;
 long diff;
 long secs;
 long mins;
 long hours;

 if(timerIsRunning)
 {
     now = System.currentTimeMillis();
 }else{
     now = endTime;
 }

 diff = now - startTime;

 if(diff < 0)
 {
     diff = 0;
 }
 /**
  * Calculate the 
  * secs,mins and hours
  */
 secs = diff / 1000;
 mins = secs  / 60;
 hours = mins / 60;
 secs = secs % 60;
 mins = mins % 60;

 display = String.format("%d", hours) + ":" +
           String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" +
           String.format("%02d", secs);


 swCounter.setText(display);
}
```

here is the log cat output

```
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695): Process: com.webdeveloper93.profitnessstopwatch, PID: 1695
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at com.webdeveloper93.profitnessstopwatch.StopwatchTimer.swTimerDisplay(StopwatchTimer.java:57)
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at com.webdeveloper93.profitnessstopwatch.timerUpdate.run(timerUpdate.java:22)
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-18 19:47:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**EDIT:**

Line 57 is swCounter.setText(display);

below is where swTimerDisplay(); is called

```
public class timerUpdate extends StopwatchTimer  implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        swTimerDisplay();
        if(handle != null)
        {
            handle.postDelayed(this, UPDATE);
        }

    }

}
```

hopefully someone can help me figure this out cause its driving me crazy :) thanks again

**EDIT:**
Here is more code as requested

```
public class Stopwatch extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private StopwatchTimer timer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stopwatch);
        //Create new instance of StopwatchTimer
        timer = new StopwatchTimer();
        timer.swCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.swcounter);
        timer.start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        timer.stop =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        timer.start.setOnClickListener(this);
        timer.stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==timer.start)
        {
            timer.timerStart();
        }else if(v==timer.stop)
        {
            timer.timerStop();
        }

    }

    public final Runnable timerUpdate = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                timer.swTimerDisplay();
                if(timer.handle != null)
                {
                timer.handle.postDelayed(this, StopwatchTimer.UPDATE); 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    };



}
```

the above is my code and swTimerDisplay is called in the run method

Comment: timerIsRunning is boolean ? or Boolean ?

Comment: Could the reference to `swCounter` be `null`?  Which line is `StopwatchTimer.java:57` anyway?

Comment: Where is `endTime` declared?

Comment: which line is line 57?

Comment: my guess would be startTime is null

Comment: If anything, you probably will have more sucess using the debugger setting a breakpoint and inspecting variables than to playing the "guess the null variable" game. The debugger is great since you're not guessing. You can see what is null and what is not.

Comment: @KevinBowersox `endTime` can only be a primitive (likely a long). @DigCamara Bad to just guess, you can infer from the OP's code that `startTime` is a primitive (likely a long).

Answer (score 0):

We need to know what "line 57" is, if you can please provide the class in which `swTimerDisplay` is called. Without this, from here I can only see two possibilities which you should check if you haven't already.

1. Your reference to `StopwatchTimer` is null, i.e. has not been instantiated,
   when you call `swTimerDisplay()`. In effect you'd be doing `null.swTimerDisplay()`.
2. In the final line of `swTimerDisplay()`, `swCounter` is null.

Edit: I just noticed that your method is protected so I would look at point 2.

Comment: Line 57 is swCounter.setText(display);

Comment: I added the extra details to my post. Thanks again

Comment: Ok i did a check on swCounter with an if statement and its indeed null. But i have set swCounter in the onCreate method using findViewById so idk why its null

Comment: @user3325917 Can you paste more code? Such as your onCreate, and indicate where swTimerDisplay() is being called in relation to this? And where the Runnable is added? You might have a race condition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition. Also double check that your `id` is correct.

Comment: Ok i added the extra code in a second edit on my post. As for the id im 100% positive its correct because i've used setText to just test it and it worked.

Comment: @user3325917 Thanks. Where are you posting the Runnable `timerUpdate`? (You might be making a `.runOnUiThread()` call somewhere perhaps.)

Comment: Right here handle = new Handler();
 update = new Stopwatch();
 handle.postDelayed(update.timerUpdate, UPDATE); inside a method called timerStart

Comment: Ok i know the problem just not how to fix it. For some reason any method or property i call inside the run method wants to throw a nullpointerexception. Even tho i create a new instance of the handler in the onCreate method when i check if its null inside the run method it is indeed null. Idk why this is happening any ideas?

Comment: I rewrote everything and it now works thanks for the help again tho :)